# preload link - wordpress and flatsome

Tags: wordpress, performance, optimization, preload

I found so many different articles and tried to implement it, but I still can't get it working.

Google pagespeed recommends to preload few files, but I can't figure it out :/

I went ahead and updated my header.php

```
<head>

    <!--custom preload -->
    <link rel="preload" as="font" crossorigin="anonymous" href="https://allurehemp.com/allurehemp/assets/css/icons/fl-icons.woff2" >
    <link rel="preload" as="style" crossorigin="anonymous" href="https://allurehemp.com/allurehemp/assets/css/fl-icons.css" >


    <meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />

    <link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11" />
    <link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>" />

    <?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>
```

And now i'm facing the following issue(s);

```
A preload for 'https://allurehemp.com/allurehemp/assets/css/fl-icons.css' is found, but is not used because the request credentials mode does not match. Consider taking a look at crossorigin attribute.
```

Any recommendation is appreciated =)

Answer (score 3):

I realize this is quite delayed, but I just figured this out for my site. Maybe it will be helpful for others, if the OP doesn't need this anymore.

It's way simpler than I thought it would be. Below is what I did, and it worked. No more warning/penalty in PageSpeed Insights, and my performance score increased.

1. In your WP admin area/dashboard, go to Flatsome > Advanced > Global Settings (see screenshot below)

[Screenshot of relevant Flatsome > Advanced > Global Settings area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jVqbv.png)

2. Insert the following line into the 'Header Scripts' area:

```html
<link rel='preload' href='//wp-content/themes/flatsome/assets/css/icons/fl-icons.woff2' as='font' type='font/woff2' crossorigin='anonymous'>
```

OTHER NOTES:

A. The link in my code snippet is relative to the site domain, so you don't need to change it and insert your domain or anything. The double slash forces the same security protocol as the origin site, so it should force load https if your site uses https (which it should).

B. This probably goes without saying, but you never know: If you're adding anything to the theme files, always use a child theme so your updates/changes don't get overwritten when you update your theme. Here's a great plugin I've used several times to create a child theme in WordPress: https://wordpress.org/plugins/child-theme-configurator/

C. The links you included in the  in the header.php file didn't include the "type=" bit. I'm not certain, but this could have been the source of the problem for you.

D. I didn't add a preload link for the css file like you did because all my css is minified and combined. Also, that particular file is just a few lines anyway, so preloading likely won't make much of a difference.

Hopefully this helps! :)

Comment: Your answer is working, but `href='//wp-content` is causing **404. not found error**, change it to: `href='/wp-content`